# How should I store another table's row in order to have statistics data in the frontend?

Tags: mysql

I have a table full of businesses each with a scannable QR Code, and another table that stores the scans the users make. Right now, the scan table schema looks like this:

`id | user_id | business_id | scanned_date`

If I want to create charts and analytics in the front-end of my Application for statistics about business scans I'd just get the business_id and get the business info with it, but the problem is that if a business' data is ever changed then the statistical data will also change, and it shouldn't be this way.

The first thing that came to my mind in order to have static data was to store the whole business row as a JSON String in a new column in the scan table, but it doesn't sound like a good practice. (Although storing JSON String is not advised against if the data won't be tampered with, which won't since it's supposed to be static).

Another thing that I thought of was to make a clone table out of the business table's schema, but that'd mean to work twice whenever I want to make changes to the original one since I must also change the cloned one.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question.

You could try having duplicates in the business table. Instead of editing the business, try adding a new one with a new id. When you are editing your business, instead of updating the existing one, you can INSERT a new one. The stats will use the old id and will not get affected by the changes. When you are trying to get the last business info, try sorting them according to their ids to get the last one. That way you won't need a second table for business data.

**Edit:** If the business `id` needs to be specific to a business, instead of using the business id, you can add a column that represents the insertion of data to the table. Again, you can use sorting limiting the query to get the last one.

**Edit 2:**

**Removing entities that were inserted a certain amount of time ago**

If you don't need the stats from a month ago, you could remove them from businesses to save up space. You can use the new time column you created to get the time difference and check if it is greater than the range you want.

Comment: I think it's a good idea, but (in terms of storage saving) wouldn't it be better to duplicate a business row right before a scan is stored, rather than every time it is edited? Maybe that's down to the frequency in which a business gets updated VERSUS the frequency of scans (which will be quite high)

Comment: Yes, as I am not quite sure about the details of scans, updates and the way you do them I can't talk for those details. That part is at your end. Good luck!

Comment: Saving the business's data along with each scan is an example of *denormalizing* your database. You probably should read about that.

Comment: @JoaquinGuevara Check my last edit about saving up space. It might help.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to represent the history of the businesses' data in your database.

You didn't mention what attributes you store in each business's row, so I will guess.  Let's say you have these columns

```
 business_id
 name
 category
 qr_code
 website
```

Your problem is this: if you change any attribute of the business, the old value vanishes.

Here's a solution to that problem.  Add `start` and `end` columns to the table. They should probably have TIMESTAMP data types.

Then, never DELETE rows from the table. When you UPDATE them, only change the value of the `end` column. Instead add new rows.  Let me explain.

For a row to be active at the time NOW(), it must pass these WHERE criteria:

```
     start_date >= NOW()
 AND (end_date IS NULL OR end_date < NOW())
```

Let's say you start with two businesses in the table.

```
business_id      start      end   name   category   qr_code   website     
          1 2019-05-01     NULL   Joe's  tavern     lkjhg12   joes.example.com
          2 2019-05-01     NULL   Acme   rockets    sdlfj48   acme.example.com
```

Good: You can count QR code scans day by day with this query

```
   SELECT COUNT(*), DATE(s.scanned_date) day, b.name
     FROM business b
     JOIN scan s ON b.business_id = s.business_id
                AND b.start >= s.scanned_date
                AND (b.end IS NULL OR b.end < s.scanned_date)
    GROUP BY DATE(s.scanned_date), b.name
```

Now, suppose Joe sells his tavern and its name changes. To represent that change you must UPDATE the existing row for Joe's to set the end date, and then INSERT a new row with the new data.  Afterward, your table looks like this

```
   business_id      start        end   name   category   qr_code   website 
(updated)    1 2019-05-01 2019-05-24   Joe's  tavern     lkjhg12   joes.example.com
(inserted)   1 2019-05-24       NULL   Fancy  tavern     lkjhg12   fancy.example.com
(unchanged)  2 2019-05-01       NULL   Acme   rockets    sdlfj48   acme.example.com
```

The query above still works, because it takes into account the start and end dates of the changes.

This approach works best when you have many more scans than changes to businesses. That seems likely in this case.

Your business table needs a composite primary key (business_id, start).

Prof. Richard Snodgrass wrote a book on this subject, *Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL*, and generously made a [pdf](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/~rts/publications.html) available.

Comment: So this is similar to Faith's answer?

Comment: Yes, it's similar. But my answer uses a time-based scheme to track changes.